# Python REST API

Tags: python, ios, django, rest

I am writing a django backend for an iPhone developer to work with (who doesn't know python). What would be the best way to document the code and API such that someone can understand what's going on without needing me to explain it?

I have heard of apiary, but I was wondering if someone could go over some of the aspects I should learn up on in order to be able to do this.

Comment: I would look at a django api app, django-rest-framework is great, it provides self documenting api and lots of built in authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a couple of tools that suit my needs (similar to yours) very well :

[Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) : one of the main Django REST apps (or framework). [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) being another one.

[Swagger](https://helloreverb.com/developers/swagger) : a very cool doc generator, compatible with both Tastypie and DRF, (almost) out of the box, and many others but I've not tried it elsewhere.

I find it (Swagger) to provide a beautiful yet simple UI for your auto-generated documentation.